Expected number of closed shapes in an $n\times n$ grid with some lines missing
I came up with a math puzzle that I can't figure out how to solve. I feel like it has enough "math" to make it more appropriate to post here than to the Puzzling Stack Exchange. Here it is (along with an example with $n=5$):

The Puzzle

Create an $n\times n$ grid of dots



Randomly connect every adjacent pair of dots with a line. There is a 50% chance for each line to show up



Count the number of closed shapes

There are two squares in the example.
Closed shapes can contain other closed shapes. For example, if two $1\times1$ squares share a side, there would be three total closed shapes (two squares and a rectangle).
My question is what the expected value $T$ of closed shapes for an $n\times n$ grid of dots?

My Attempt
I do not know how to approach this problem mathematically. I know there will be $2n(n-1)$ total lines multiplied by a $1/2$ chance for each to appear so I can expect an average of $n^2-n$ lines to show up each time. I do not know where to go with this information.
For $n=2$, the expected value is obviously $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^4=\frac{1}{16}$ but even $n=3$ looks to complex for me to brute force.
I created a desmos graph to make it easier for me to collect data but I do not have the programming skills necessary to code something that will detect all of the shapes or iterate over all of the possibilities.
For $n=3$, $50$ repetitions gave me an average of $0.32$ which is honestly a lot smaller than I expected. I would want more repetitions but it is very time consuming to do by hand.
Also, I just realized that a closed shape could also be thought of as a closed loop. I doubt this helps with anything though.

How exactly do you define "closed shape"?  Is it allowed to be self-intersecting, e.g. do two squares meeting at a vertex count as a single "shape" as well as the individual squares?

@RobertIsrael I am not counting self-intersecting shapes as closed so it would be counted as two squares.

Linearity of expectation reduces this to finding the number of closed shapes for each perimeter length $p$; call that count $C(p)$.  Then your answer is just $\sum_p C(p)/2^p$.

For $n=3$, it seems like $C(4)=C(6)=4$ and $C(8)=5$.  So the answer should be $1/4+1/16+5/256 = 85/256$ or $\approx 0.332$, which seems to agree with your simulation.

Look up: "self-avoiding polygons".

The link to your Desmos graph is broken by the way. For more information about the $C(p)$ a previous commenter brought up, see the section here starting with "The numbers of (undirected) graph cycles".
